# package incompatible version after upgrading flutter

Tags: flutter-dependencies

My Flutter app depends on intl_utils: ^1.6.3, and today I upgraded Fluter to the latest `Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-2.0.pre.86, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287 darwin-x64, locale en-US)`.

Now when I run pub get I get this error:

```
Because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2 and intl_translation >=0.17.7 depends on intl >=0.15.3 <0.17.0, flutter_localizations from sdk is incompatible with intl_translation >=0.17.7.

Because intl_utils >=1.6.3 <1.9.0 depends on intl_translation 0.17.10 and intl_utils >=1.9.0 depends on intl_translation 0.17.10+1, intl_utils >=1.6.3 requires intl_translation 0.17.10 or 0.17.10+1.
Thus, flutter_localizations from sdk is incompatible with intl_utils >=1.6.3.
So, because xxx depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and intl_utils ^1.6.3, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because xxx depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and intl_utils ^1.6.3, version solving failed.)
```

so I added `intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2` and  `intl_translation: ^0.17.10+1` but now I get this

```
Because intl_translation >=0.17.7 depends on intl >=0.15.3 <0.17.0 and xxx depends on intl ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2, intl_translation >=0.17.7 is forbidden.
So, because xxx depends on intl_translation ^0.17.10+1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because xxx depends on intl_translation ^0.17.10+1, version solving failed.)
```

I then changed to `intl_translation: 0.17.6` and now the error is:

```
Because intl_translation >=0.17.0 <0.17.7 depends on intl ^0.15.3 and xxx depends on intl ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2, intl_translation >=0.17.0 <0.17.7 is forbidden.

So, because gipi_partner depends on intl_translation 0.17.6, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1; So, because xxx depends on intl_translation 0.17.6, version solving failed.)
```

I'm trying all combinations of versions but none is working.
Should I just downgrade Flutter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

a temporary workaround you can override the dependency in `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.17.0
```

Comment: Indeed is what I'm doing at the moment. Thanks for the answer, I forgot to put one myself.

Answer (score 2):

it's best you downgrade there are compatibility issue with the newer version.

Comment: I did downgrade flutter and now iOS project won't build..
I get 
`In file included from /Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-0.3.24/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:5:
    /Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-0.3.24/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>`

Comment: i sugguest u re-install flutter, it's on verge of breaking maybe due to some SDK files downgrading. simplest solution is that u re-install it if it's feasible.

Comment: I thought so.. it's really annoying that the upgrade/downgrade tools mess up the sdk ...

Comment: how to solve this isseus with the new update ?

Comment: I solve the issue by:
dependency_overrides:
  intl: any